# How to compare 2 cells to another 2 cells in a different sheet in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I want to know how to compare or know the difference of 2 cells to another 2 cells in a different sheet in excel 2007

Example:

Sheet 1

```
   A     B
1 101   KIWI
2 102   APPLE
3 103   BANANA
```

Sheet 2

```
   A     B
1 101   KIWI
2 102   APPLE
3 103   ORANGE
```

I want to show the there is a difference in 3rd row on Sheet 1 and 2

Thanks

Comment: *where* do you want to show the difference?  Are you saying in cell A4 = "B2"?

Answer (score 1):

If you put `=A1&B1` in C1 of each sheet and copy down then it is like comparing single columns. So with, in D1:

in Sheet1:  `=MATCH(C1,Sheet2!C:C,0)`
in Sheet2:  `=MATCH(C1,Sheet1!C:C,0)`

copied down in each case the resulting numbers should show the row number where the match is on the 'other sheet' (the lists need not be sorted) and otherwise `#N/A` for where matches have not been found.

There is obviously no need for the concatenation for the example provided, since the two 'A' columns are identical, but I take it that was because the example was simplified.

[image: SO18394321 example]

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks a lot. 
Yes this was simplified because my excel file has more than 700 rows.